# the find function in typeorm return field with __underscores__

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have entity in typeorm defined as:

```
@Entity('foo', { schema: 'dbo' })
export class Foo extends BaseEntity {

  ...
  @ManyToMany(() => Bar, (bar) => bar.some, { lazy: true })
  bars: Promise<Bar[]>
}
```

when I using `find` the results come out with underscore instead the normal object (`bars`):

```
const results = await Foo.find({ relations: ['bars'] });

results.__bars__ // <--------- this should be just `bars`.
```

This is normal behavior of typeorm? if not how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That caused by activating lazy loading `{ lazy: true }`, just for your information may they abandoned this feature [see this](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3703#issuecomment-467135431), as a solution may you remove this feature or make a map for the result.

**PS**: even though I tried the similar case and I even get the underscores, I got the `bars` by doing `results.bars`